# When are True not or etcetera used in c instead of operators like &&, ||, !=, =

Tags: c, operators

I mean I notice that the actual words do exist in C,and light up when i write them but how do I use them instead of "normal" operators like `==`  `!=`  `&&`  `||` .For example to do something like this sample code(P.S I know it's not right syntax it's just to explain what I mean):

```
if not(stuff==3 and otherStuff==5)
  printf("something");
else if(statement==false)
  printf("some else");
```

Comment: with etc I meant and so on,btw if not isn't in c why does it light up,if i write it,it's confusing

Comment: Ah alright,then all I've tried till now are  broken too,even the online one are.

Comment: @fredrik actually the stack overflow editor thinks and highlights this as C++...

Answer (score 5):

The new highlighter on Stack Overflow is very broken. But it is also true that you **can** use `and` and `not` in C - for those you just need to `#include <iso646.h>`.

They're not keywords but macros, though.

Answer (score 1):

*"...actual words do exist in C"*

The `C` language keywords are [defined here](http://www.dii.uchile.cl/%7Edaespino/files/Iso_C_1999_definition.pdf).

Other words you might see used, such as `true`, `TRUE`, `false`, are probably defined within the environment you are using.
Eg: Common-Predefined-Macros typical to a [GCC environment](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html), and the `#define`s for `true` and `false` included in header file `<stdbool.h>` (from @Shawn in comments) are two examples of how other symbols may be available to you

Comment: They're keywords in C++, but in C you need to include the right header. And `<stdbool.h>` provides `true` and `false`.

Comment: @Shawn - Thanks.  The GCC link was included because it is very common, and it does cover symbols used for C as well.  And I quoted you for credit for the `true/false`.

Comment: Linking to a random programming website as reference doesn't seem like a good idea. Maybe link to the C standard if you really want to...

Comment: @MarcoBonelli - Edited with a better link.